# ArgumentError in new for an enum parameter in rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a model, Announcement, with an enum

```
Audience = ['everyone', 'signed_in_only','visitor_only', 'app_only', 'exclude_app']
enum audience: Audience
```

The announcements controller defines audience_params

```
def announcement_params
  params.require(:announcement).permit(:body, :audience, :expiry)
end
```

In creating an announcement, the audience_params are

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"This is for everyone", "audience"=>"0", "expiry"=>"27/01/2018"} permitted: true>
```

My code in the action method of the announcements controller includes

```
@announcement = Announcement.new(announcement_params)
@announcement.audience = @announcement.audience.to_i
```

which worked with rails 5.0.  But now the first line throws an exception

```
ArgumentError: '0' is not a valid audience
```

presumably because the audience value has not been converted to integer.  Given the new method does not do validations, why is this error being thrown in rails 5.1 and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`enum` is meant to allow you to use symbolic names rather than numbers. The accessors they define expect you to give a string or symbol, rather than the underlying numeric value.

You should be using

```
@announcement.audience = 'everyone'
```

not

```
@announcement.audience = 0
```

This behavior may have changed in newer Rails, but the *correct* thing has always been to assign the human-readable string, not the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5.2 you can call .to_sym on the passed string and model creates and saves.  As regards to just using the string, hmmm, there's probably a reason the automagic isn't working in my case so I'd try that first.